# I need to compare cell A1 to cell A2 and put the result in A3 If all words in any order

Tags: excel

I need to determine if all the words in cell A1 are also in cell A2.  If they are, I need cell A3 to show True, otherwise false.

If all the words in A1 are in A2 in any order then put True in cell A3 otherwise put false in cell A3

Example

A1 - "Tony Stewart Child Medium"
A2 - "California Costumes Nascar Tony Stewart Child Costume, Medium"

Result True.

Example

A1 - "Tony Stewart Child Medium"
A2 - "California Costumes Nascar Tony Stewart Child Costume"

Result False.

Comment: What's the question ? you need a solution ? script ??? function ??? please be clear...

Comment: script, function, macro, Anything i can use in excel to accomplish this.

Answer (score 3):

you can do something like this insize of A3:

```
=IF(FIND(A1, A2), "True", "False")
```

Comment: that just returns an error. I need to find all the words in A1 in A2. Each word in A1 in eve if they are not next to each other. Finding all words in A2  need return a result of TRUE. This formula only works if the words are in the same order. Think of A1 as just a list of words each independent of each other but all have to be in A2 in order = TRUE

Comment: im not sure how you are doign this, but the above does not return an error, i am testing it in excel 2007 and 2013. As of checking each individual word you will have to use a macro. Do you need help understanding how to write macros? i can help you, but wont code the whole thing for you lol

Comment: I inserted the formula in A3. The result is only true if all the words in A1are in  the same order in A2. I think what needs to be done some how have A1 be a word list and compare each word in the list to A2 and return a TRUE result if all words in the list are in A2. Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You definitely need a macro, see this for example on how to traverse a list using a macro, https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/299036 but instead of traversing rows, traverse an array. To create an array using "space" as delimiter which is what you need, see this article https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/266289